# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: OperationalError: near "<": syntax error

Tags: python, discord.py, sqlite3-python

I am running arch linux with GNOME desktop. I have a virtual enviroment in python named `venv`. I have installed `sqlite3` and `discord.py`. I am using cogs for commands.

I wanted to fetch `tokens` from my localdb in sqlite3.
my code for `db.py` is

```
import sqlite3


class database:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("db.db")
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()

    def update(self, name, value, id) -> bool:
        self.c.execute(f"UPDATE users SET {name}={value} WHERE id={id}")
        self.conn.commit()
        if self.c.rowcount < 1:
            return False
            # error
        else:
            return True
            # success

    def fetch(self, name, id):
        self.c.execute(f"SELECT {name} FROM users WHERE id={id}")
        res = self.c.fetchone()
        if res:
            return res
        else:
            return "No user found"
```

and code for the cog which i am using it in is named `russian_roulette.py`

```
tokens= db.fetch("tokens",id)
if tokens == 'No user found':
    await ctx.reply('Create an account first by running `.start`')
else:
    tokens=sum(tokens)
```

The fetch function returns (100,) which is parsed into sum() function to convert it into an int. But it is giving this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jivesh/Desktop/Projects/discord_bots/game/gambler/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jivesh/Desktop/Projects/discord_bots/game/gambler/cogs/russian_roulette.py", line 18, in roulette
    tokens= db.fetch("tokens",id)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jivesh/Desktop/Projects/discord_bots/game/gambler/cogs/db/db.py", line 20, in fetch
    self.c.execute(f"SELECT {name} FROM users WHERE id={id}")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "<": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jivesh/Desktop/Projects/discord_bots/game/gambler/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/jivesh/Desktop/Projects/discord_bots/game/gambler/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jivesh/Desktop/Projects/discord_bots/game/gambler/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: OperationalError: near "<": syntax error
```

But there is no error in my syntax in sql. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: We don't know what's in your `name` or `id`, but because you used f-strings (which you should **never** do for SQL) they're being injected into the query as text before it's run. There could well be a `<` in one of them!

Comment: Start by introducing yourself to [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/), or just read the fine docs at https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/sqlite3.html, which show you how to **correctly** introduce variables to your queries.

Comment: I remmebered that this happened to me a while ago and after some google searching, i found out that i forgot to make the variable id. Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: Just assigning a value to id doesn't stop you from having major security problems if that's the only change you make. **Really**, read and follow the links above.

Comment: (for a rough introduction to what I'm talking about, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)